# How to properly manage application configurations

Tags: python, configuration

What is the most universal and best application configurations management method? I want to have these properties in order to have "good configuration management":

- A list of all available properties and their default values in one
  place.
- A list of properties which can be changed by an app user, also in one
  place.
- When I retrieve a specific property, it's value is returned from the
  2nd list (user changeable configs) or if it's not there, from the
  first list.

So far, what I did was hard coding the 1st list as an object (more specific as a `dict`), wrote `.conf` file used by `ConfigParser` to make an app user to easily change some of the properties (2nd list), and wrote a public method on the config object to retrieve a property by it's name or if it's not there, raise an exception. In the end, one object was responsible for managing all the stuff (parsing file, raising exception, overriding properties etc.) But I was wondering, if there's a built-in library which does more or less the same thing, or even a better way to manage configuration, which takes into account all the KISS, DRY and other principles (I'm not always successful to do that with this method)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't follow, `ConfigParser` is built-in and seems to be adaptable for your use case, KISS and DRY are your responsibility and should be possible with a little thought. - Of course you could use `pickle` or `marshal` to save the entire state of your app, but then this isn't configurable.

Comment: `ConfigParser` is really what you want to use here. I'm a little confused by your explanation though. Is there a specific reason you can't/don't want to use `ConfigParser`?

Comment: I can use it, and do use it, but `ConfigParser` is a bit too low level, I was wondering if there's a way to do it with more abstraction. I thought that what I'm trying to achieve is a common task, so just wanted to ask if anybody else has a better way to manage configurations. Thanks allot for your responses

Answer (score 0):

Create a default settings module which contains your desired default settings. Create a second module intended to be used by the the user with a `from default_settings import *` statement at the top, and instructing the user to write any replacements into this module instead.

Python is rather expressive, so in most cases, if you can expect the user to understand it on any level, you can use a Python module itself as the configuration file.